# Why my data is not loading back when I erase the searchTerm passed to Input field in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, json-server

I am making a search functionality into react that effectively looks for data from json-server for a match. I don't want to provide a debounced search to the input field, rather I want to trigger the search when "Enter" key is pressed. So i used onKeyPress prop from MUI's textfield, where I provided the logic to send the query to the server.

Please acknowledge my code as mentioned below -

```
    imports...
    
    
    export default function AppSearchBar ( ) {
    // local state for searchTerm
    const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm ] = useState<string>('');
    
    // using redux - action
    const {loadedBooks} = useAppSelector(state => state.books);
    const {loadedGames} = useAppSelector(state => state.games);
    // these 'loadedBooks' and 'loadedGames' are of type boolean and are initially false (coming from my slices) and set to true when their requests are getting fulfilled.
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    
    // useCallback
    const fetchAllCategories = useCallback(() => {
      setTimeout( async () => {
          await dispatch(fetchBooksAsync( searchTerm )); // this is async thunks i created to fetch books into my bookSlice.ts file
          await dispatch(fetchGamesAsync( searchTerm )); // this is async thunks i created to fetch books into my gameSlice.ts file
        }, 500);
     }, [ searchTerm , dispatch ]);
    
    // effect when searchTerm mounts
   /* useEffect(() => {
      fetchAllCategories()
    }, [ fetchAllCategories ]); */ // dependency as the function itself.
    // I want this useEffect, but un-commenting this is not allowing my "handleSearchOnEnter" to come into the picture at all, but, I want that first load of all cars be automatic, and then when I write something to input, on pressing enter it should search, and finally when I wipe input field, it should return me back all the cards.
    
    
    const handleSearchOnEnter = ( event : any ) => {
      if ( event.key === "Enter" ) {
              fetchAllCategories(); // this is wrapped inside of useCallBack and effect is produced using useEffect.
    }}
    
    
      return (
            <Fragment>
    
                    <TextField
                     value = {searchTerm}
                     onChange = {( event : any ) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
                     onKeyPress = { searchTerm !== "" ? handleSearchOnEnter : undefined } />
    
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Now, problem statement -

1. Whenever I load my window, all Books and Games are not loaded at all (if I remove useEffect() from code). They only loads when I press enter. But, I don't want this behaviour.
2. If I keep useEffect() - hook, then they behaves like debounce search and onChange of my text input field, they return the searched result.
3. **What I want is as follows -**
   - Whenever I first loads the window, all products get loaded.
   - Whenever I write something into the input field, then it shouldn't call (fetchFiltersAsync() - which is the API call for full-text search on Json-Server) until i press Enter key, only When I press enter, it should call the API and fetch the relevant results.
   - After that, when I manually remove the searchedItem from input field (wiping it), all of my data should get returned. (i.e display all cards into UI)

*What is Happening? -*

1. Whenever My window loads, all of my data/cards are not getting loaded., until I presses enter key...cool
2. When I type something into input field, it fetches the searched results without even taking "Enter" (because of open useEffect() into the code)
3. When I remove a term from the input field, my data is not getting loaded automatically back to like as they were into first visit (all cards visible).

All controls are here only (into the code), I have to do something with `searchTerm`, so whenever searchTerm is not empty, then my handleSearchOnEnter() function should get called.
I mean, it should produce useEffect automatically, but only when a searchTerm is not being provided. If the searchTerm is being provided, then it should trigger handleOnEnterSearch()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that is described in the second Problem I solved it by adding  in my project.

```
<form onSubmit={onKeyDownHandler}>
  <TextField>{"Some Code"}</TextField>
</form>;
```

Also you can create an useState and giving it new Date will refresh your table better.

```
const onKeyDownHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // if (searchTxt.length >= 3 || !searchTxt.length) {
    dispatch(setSearchTxt(searchTxtTemp));
    setTriggerSearch(new Date().getTime());
  // }
};
```

But the bad sides of this code is when you remove everything from input you need to press enter again to refresh.

Comment: hey, could you please elaborate what you want to suggest? When I remove everything , i dont want to press enter

Comment: It was just a suggestion for this problem. "When I type something into input field, it fetches the searched results without even taking "Enter" (because of open useEffect() into the code)". 

Maybe you can set a condition inside the useEffect which takes the input.length and when that input length becomes 0 you can request whole data.